# Asymptote binary tree, how to I insert something else than numbers

Tags: asymptote

Asymptote has a binary tree library. But when I try to write something else than numbers, an error message comes.

MWE from the Asymptote documentation:

```
import binarytree;

picture pic,pic2;

binarytree bt=binarytree(1,2,4,nil,5,nil,nil,0,nil,nil,3,6,nil,nil,7);
draw(pic,bt,condensed=false);

binarytree st=searchtree(10,5,2,1,3,4,7,6,8,9,15,13,12,11,14,17,16,18,19);
draw(pic2,st,blue,condensed=true);

add(pic.fit(),(0,0),10N);
add(pic2.fit(),(0,0),10S);
```

I would like to write something else into the circles, for example variables, and let some cirles empty. How to do that?